# UDP Client and Service

Tags: android-studio, udp

Нужно данные с блютуза передать на UDP Server в Service, но для теста хотя бы String: ("The String to Send").getBytes();

```
MyService.UdpClientThread udpClientThread;

    public class UdpClientThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            DatagramSocket udpSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("3753330000000.dyndns.mts.by");
            byte[] buf = ("The String to Send").getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,serverAddr, 4445);
            udpSocket.send(packet);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("Udp:", "Socket Error:", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Udp Send:", "IO Error:", e);
        }
    }
}

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    readFlags(flags);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    myThreadConnected.start(); //при запуске вылетает Service (приложение)
    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Класс приёма данных по Bluetooth и отправка данных по UDP Client-Server

        private class ThreadConnected extends Thread {    // Поток - приём и отправка данных
        private final BluetoothSocket copyBtSocket;
        private final InputStream connectedInputStream; //приём
        private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream; //отправка

        private String sbprint;

        public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            copyBtSocket = socket;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectedInputStream = in;
            connectedOutputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() { // Приём данных
            while (true) {
                try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            int bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
            String strIncom = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            sb.append(strIncom); // собираем символы в строку
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n"); // определяем конец строки
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {

                sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "***приём: " + sbprint+ "***"  );
                try {

                                     DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("375333000000.dyndns.mts.by");
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

                    sendData = sbprint.getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 4445);
                    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Штопор1");
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
        }
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void sendData(String message) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "***Отправляем данные по Bluetooth: " + message + "***"  );

            try {
                connectedOutputStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        public void cancel(){
            try {
                copyBtSocket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }
        public Object status_OutStrem(){
            if (connectedOutputStream == null){return null;
            }else{return connectedOutputStream;}
        }
    }
```